# Duplicate Tab vs Open Link In new Tab

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, chrome, browser

On my chrome browser, when I right click on browser tab and select **duplicate** and then perform a search on the duplicated tab, the original tab also hangs until things are loaded in the duplicate tab.

But same if I just copy paste the URL in a different tab or right click and select **open in new tab**, operations in the new tab don't hang the original tab.

Need to know the reason behind the different behavior and how duplicate is different from open link in new tab.